# Mageto2:How to Sort products by regular price?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to sort products by regular not final price or special price.
any idea how to do that
Here you can see special price and regualr price.
[image]

and this is my code.

> Vendor\module\Model\VisualMerchandiser\Sorting\OriginalPriceTop.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\module\Model\VisualMerchandiser\Sorting;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection as CollectionAlias;
use Magento\VisualMerchandiser\Model\Sorting\SortAbstract;
use Magento\VisualMerchandiser\Model\Sorting\SortInterface;
use Zend_Db_Select;

class OriginalPriceTop extends SortAbstract implements SortInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function sort(
        Collection $collection
    ): Collection {
        $this->addPriceData($collection);
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->distinct('entity_id')
            ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)
            ->order('price ' . CollectionAlias::SORT_ORDER_DESC);

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLabel(): string
    {
        return __("Original Price Top");
    }
}
```

**Is this code good or its needs to change?**

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, again question from you about the same topic and without any answers

This code should work and I think here is everything is OK

I just can suggest to use correlation table for price field for prevent any ambiguous cases. Just change `order('price '` to `order('price_index.price '`

Good luck and I hope you already received some experience to write Magento things

Comment: Thanks, i'm  still learning, long way to go

Comment: the client wants 30 custom sorting options, 10 were already implemented, 15 were implemented with your help and still 5 remaining. so....